# Vanilla javascript: Get a specific element of page in an ajax get request

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm trying to get `#test1` from another page and append it to `#test3` of the main page. This is what I have done so far:

```html
<div id="test3"></div>
```

```js
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', '//jsbin.com/wemowe', true);

request.onload = function() {
  if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
    var resp = request.responseText;  
    var parser = new DOMParser();
    var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(resp,"text/xml");
    var tds = xmlDoc.getElementById("test1");
    console.log(xmlDoc);
    document.getElementById('test3').innerHTML=tds.innerHTML;
  } else {}
};

request.onerror = function() {};

request.send();
```

[Here is JSBin](http://jsbin.com/yureta)

Any suggestion to make it work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The doc type is causing the issue here.

```
var xmlDoc=parser.parseFromString(resp, "text/xml");
```

change it to:

```
var xmlDoc=parser.parseFromString(resp, "text/html");
```